# Menu active current page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, adminlte

I'm using Bootstrap (AdminLTE) and I want to make the current page's menu item active.
Problem is, I don't know how to do it.
I do have a few solutions in mind (besides changing it in every php file), like putting an IF statement for every link, which would be a terrible solution (I think).

```
      <ul class="sidebar-menu">
        <li class="header">HOOFD MENU</li>
        <li class='treeview'>
          <a href='#'>
            <i class='fa fa-dashboard'></i> <span>Dashboard</span>
            <span class='pull-right-container'>
              <i class='fa fa-angle-left pull-right'></i>
            </span>
          </a>
          <ul class='treeview-menu'>
            <li><a href='account.php'><i class='fa fa-circle-o'></i>Account</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
</ul>
```

The above is part of the menu.
So the menu item (in this case Dashboard) and sub-menu item both have to become active.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this. This was copied from other bootstrap admin template and modified for AdminLTE

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = window.location; 
        var element = $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function() {
        return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0; }).parent().addClass('active');
        if (element.is('li')) { 
             element.addClass('active').parent().parent('li').addClass('active')
         }
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: Around where does it need to be placed? Can it just be a php file that gets included?

Comment: I tried including it and I put it in a template(which contains the menu etc) at the bottom of the body tag. I also put the code in a script tag. Doesnt seem to work somehow.

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4):

This solution work with sublevel menu. Need JQuery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var url = window.location;
        var element = $('ul.sidebar-menu a').filter(function () {
            return this.href == url || url.href.indexOf(this.href) == 0;
        });
        $(element).parentsUntil('ul.sidebar-menu', 'li').addClass('active');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

In one simple line:

```
$("ul.sidebar-menu li a[href='"+document.location.pathname+"']").parents('li').addClass('active');
```

Answer (score 0):

So you should always check to make sure the element exists so you don't get any errors and you can user jQuery's data attribute selector to easily target the correct links.

```
var href = window.location.pathname;

if( $(".sidebar-menu a[href='"+href+"']").length ) {
    $(".sidebar-menu a[href='"+href+"']").parent('li').addClass('active');
}
```

If you are using absolute urls you may need to switch from .pathname to .href in the var